# Can XWPFDocument be converted to a Byte[] without saving it to a file first?

Tags: arrays, apache-poi, xwpf

is it possible to convert a `XWPFDocument` to `byte[]`? I don't want to save it into a file because I don't need it. if there is a possible way to do it, it would help

Comment: [POIXMLDocument.write](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLDocument.html#write-java.io.OutputStream-) takes an `java.io.OutputStream` as parameter. That also can be a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: can you give more explanation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [XWPFDocument](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html) extends [POIXMLDocument](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLDocument.html) and it's [write](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLDocument.html#write-java.io.OutputStream-) method takes an java.io.OutputStream as parameter. That also can be a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. So if the need is to get a `XWPFDocument` as an byte array, then write it into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then get the array from the method [ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray--).

Example:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateXWPFDocumentAsByteArray {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.setBold(true);
  run.setFontSize(22);
  run.setText("The paragraph content ...");
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

  byte[] xwpfDocumentBytes = out.toByteArray();
  // do something with the byte array
  System.out.println(xwpfDocumentBytes);

  // to prove that the byte array really contains the XWPFDocument 
  try (FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("./XWPFDocument.docx")) {
    stream.write(xwpfDocumentBytes);
  } 

 }
}
```