# How can I dump XML body of XWPFDocument?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

Using Java 8, and Apache POI and Apache POI-OOXML 4.1.2, we are converting documents from an XML-based derivative of EPUB3 into the DOCX format.   I'm new to the project, and am trying to debug something.  As part of my debugging toolkit, I'd like to dump the XML in the equivalent of the document.xml file within a .docx file to a string that I can print out or save.

I tried `XWPFWordExtractor`, but that seems to print out text and not XML.
I also tried `.toString()`, which appears to print out the address of the object, and iterating through the results of `getBodyElementsIterator()`, which isn't quite it either.

This helped me print bytes, but not the XML I wanted:
[Can XWPFDocument be converted to a Byte[] without saving it to a file first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58536711/can-xwpfdocument-be-converted-to-a-byte-without-saving-it-to-a-file-first)

I just want something like

```
public void dumpDocx(final XWPFDocument docx) {
    System.out.println(docx.getBody().toXml().toString());
}
```

And I'd like the output to be the XML representing the contents of document.xml.

Comment: Save the overall `XWPFDocument` to a temp file or byte array, open it as a zip and read back the `document.xml` within? (Or grab it from OPCPackage if that's easier)

Comment: Have you tried `System.out.println(docx.getDocument().toString());`? This should print the `XML` of the underlying `CTDocument1`. But for debugging reasons simply unzip the `*.docx` and have a look at `word/document.xml`.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you, that works.  The reason I'd rather not stop and reopen a file is that we have a list of successive filters we wrote that update the document in memory and if I don't know what plugin is making a bad update I'll have to write a copy, unzip, and read after every filter runs to see what changes it made.  It's a viable workaround, but I'd rather not do unnecessary file saves or manual intervention.  If you add the `.getDocument` solution as an answer I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `*.docx` file is simply a `ZIP` archive containing multiple `XML` files and other files too. So after `XWPFDocument.write` the result, either a file or bytes, can be handled as such, unzipped and looked at `/word/document.xml` for example.

But if one wants avoid writing out the whole document, then one needs to know that `XWPFDocument` internally bases on `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CT*` objects which all extend `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject`. And `XmlObject.toString()` returns the `XML` as `String`. For the document `XML`,  `XWPFDocument.getDocument` returns a `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDocument1` which is the representaton of `/word/document.xml`.

So `System.out.println(docx.getDocument().toString());` will print the XML of the underlying `CTDocument1`.

Unfortunately `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject` only represents the contents of an element or attribute, not the element or attribute itself. So when you validate or save an `XmlObject`, you are validating or saving its contents, not its container. For `CTDocument1` that means, it contains the body elements but not the document container itself. To get the document container itself as an `XmlObject` one needs a `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument` object which contains the `CTDocument1`.

Example for print document `XML` from `XWPFDocument`:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateXWPFDocumentDumpDocumentXML {
    
 static void printDocumentXML(XWPFDocument docx) throws Exception {
     
  String xml;
  
  System.out.println("Contents of org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDocument1:");
  org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject documentXmlObject = docx.getDocument();
  xml = documentXmlObject.toString();  
  System.out.println(xml);   
  
  System.out.println("Contents of whole DocumentDocument:");
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDocument1 ctDocument1 = docx.getDocument();
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument documentDocument = org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument.Factory.newInstance();
  documentDocument.setDocument​(ctDocument1);
  xml = documentDocument.toString();
  System.out.println(xml);
  
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = docx.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.setBold(true);
  run.setFontSize(22);
  run.setText("The paragraph content ...");
  paragraph = docx.createParagraph();

  printDocumentXML(docx);

  try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./XWPFDocument.docx")) {
    docx.write(out);
  } 

 }
}
```